# Is there a visual tool to connect components together, with suggestions on missing part

Tags: visualization

I'm not great in electronics but would love to play with micro controller and connecting sensors to it.
In my mind, it would mean loading specific micro controller details on that tool (like, say, the ESP8266), and a sensor, for instance, a temperature sensor. Connecting them together would mean adding a resistor that the tool would do automatically, based on what is needed.
The connection between the two would be made automatically (like connecting the sensor on the ground, and the analog 1 (or digital 1, depending on the sensor).

Once everything is connected, you know what to purchase and how to connect them.

Am I asking for too much? I definitely not have the knowledge here.

Comment: yes, the visual tool is called a schematic diagram

Comment: Not sure if such a tool exists, but a simpler solution could be to use boards using a common connection system, like Seeed’s Grove connector, or Sparkfun’s Qwiik/Adafruit’s Stemma QT, or M5Stack’s HAT... Note that they may be a little bit deceptive as the same connector may be used for different things (analog signals, digital signals, I2C or SPI), and for some there are 3.3V or 5V devices, but the product pages are usually explicit about the details. Sensors using those connectors have the necessary circuitry on the PCB, so you just connect then configure your software to use the right pins.

Comment: Might want to look into pspice, it's a electronic prototype simulator. It won't **tell you** what parts to use, but you can add in different parts, and probe your design to see what voltage current readings are after a resistor ect. It's a very useful learning tool